# Rust - How to migrate '\uXXXX' to new bytes string

Tags: migration, rust

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to translate following old Rust code:

```
  bytes!("a\u2028t")
```

Into current language. It seems `bytes!` was deprecated by `b""` but I don't see a way to translate `\u2028` into a byte string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a true byte string equivalent, you'll need to find the UTF8 encoding of U+2028, e.g. via

```
fn main() {
    for b in "\u2028".as_bytes().iter() { print!("\\x{:x}", *b) }
}
```

which prints `\xe2\x80\xa8` (i.e. in pre-encoded form), so `b"a\xe2\x80\xa8t"` should work. Also, the above hints at another method: you can often use `"a\u2028t".as_bytes()`, although this will not work in `static` contexts.

Comment: Could I use "\u2028".as_bytes()?